# how to put a jQuery $ (..).click (function () { inside a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to put a  `$(..).click(function () {...`  inside a javascript object, but I feel like I'm asking for the impossible.

Inside this object there can be several Dom elements, so I think that making a jQuery extension is excluded too?
But I admit, I can not understand how to make an jQuery extension, there are still concepts that escape me in this respect.

Anyway, here's an example of what I'm looking to do, even if it's not functional:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  class bt_Fab {
    constructor($elem_ID, $messageBox_ID, message) {
      this.$_ID = $elem_ID;
      this.$_ID_MsgBox = $messageBox_ID;
      this._msg = message;

      this.$_ID.click(function() {
        this.$_ID_MsgBox.text(this._msg); // does nothing...
      });
    }
  };

  var
    myOneButton = new bt_Fab($('#btn_one'), $('#messageBox'), 'message from button one!'),
    myTwoButton = new bt_Fab($('#btn_two'), $('#messageBox'), 'message from button two!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btn_one'>button One</button>
<button id='btn_two'>button Two</button>
<!-- lot of html here -->
<div id="messageBox">... </div>
```

[ Update Edit ] ( for @Sam Hanley & @meagar )
This question is different from [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)
because this question is about the use of jQuery function inside a Javascript Object; and they are not about the corect usage of a `this` in Javascript object model.

Comment: try `this.$_ID.addEventListener('click', event => { /* add your code*/});` instead.

Comment: if `$_ID` is just the id of the existing element. You need to get element by `document.getElementById`.

Comment: BTW, you're not targetting your HTML elements correctly: `$('btn_one')` should be `$('#btn_one')` etc.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cgfpjrtq/

Comment: [Me too!](https://jsfiddle.net/1n7gs2za/2/)

Comment: to every one: thank !, (spécialy @ZITAL)

Comment: @ Sam Hanley, meagar   duplicate, but Where ??, i have done a search before...!

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, within a event handler such as `$.click()`, the `this` keyword is overriden with the reference to the sender object, in this case `$_ID`. In `this.$_ID.click`, `this` is actually the instance of the class. Inside of the click handler, i.e. `function() { this.msgBox... }`, `this` refers to the element that was clicked.

When I create a class in javascript, I usually create a class variable called `my` that I set to `this` in the constructor of the class. Instead of using `this` use the `my` variable when you're using jQuery to avoid confusion.

Sometimes it's actually nice that `this` is overridden, but when you're defining a class it's just horrible.

Comment: This was just for example. I use myself a 'my=this;' in my Javascript objects.

Comment: How would you call the variable "my" without calling "this" ?

Comment: I dont really know tbh now that I look at this again. I think what I meant here is that I would create a variable called `my` if I can create it outside of the scope of the jQuery event handling. Meaning the `my` variable already exists within the scope. I dont know if I meant this in the context of a class member when I typed this, and I dont really know at this time.

Comment: Got it, Thank you.